# Exclude files from solution-wide Code Cleanup in Resharper

Tags: .net, resharper

Is there a way to exclude certain files from Resharper's Code Cleanup? I have a range of generated files I'd like to leave untouched.

I found the below question, however the answer's there are workaround's for the specific issue, and don't answer how to actually exclude files. (If it's possible)

[Is there a resharper comment directive to disable code cleanup for a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3214894/1768779)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you go to ReSharper Options > Generated Code and add your file to the list of Generated Code or Generated File masks then it will be skipped by the Code Cleanup process.

[image: Picture of the relevant pane of the ReSharper options]

Comment: Does that work for code-clean-up too? I didn't realise! Thank you, I'll check it out later and see if it's successful.

Comment: It did when I just tried it ;). I'm using ReSharper 9.2 RC at the moment.

Comment: In newer versions of R# there is also the *Code Editing | Third-Party Code* section that can be useful for excluding things that are not generated.

Comment: This does not appear to affect code cleanup, at least not on Rider 2023.1.3.