# Can I make sure resharper does not change the order of the fields in this class?

Tags: resharper, structlayout

I'm using [this NetResource class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to send files to a network drive and it looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplayType DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}
```

Now it's very important that the order of these fields stay the same, as hinted on by the `StructLayout` attribute.

However, when someone would run a resharper cleanup, resharper decides to move the fields around and that would break the code.

Is there any way of telling rehsarper to not mess with it? I feel like if I can't do that, someone is going to eventually break the code and have no idea where to look.

But a mediocre solution to that I think would be to create a unittest that can check if there layout is as expected.

Edit: I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214894/is-there-a-resharper-comment-directive-to-disable-code-cleanup-for-a-class), but it is outdated and requires resharper settings to be updated. I will also not be guaranteed that coworkers use this resharper setting. I'm looking for a way to add it in the code, just like you can do `// ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a resharper comment directive to disable code cleanup for a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214894/is-there-a-resharper-comment-directive-to-disable-code-cleanup-for-a-class)

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of solutions here:

- You might mark the class with `NoReorderAttribute` from the [JetBrains.Annotations](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/) (there are several ways to add them to a project). Then ReSharper will stop reordering members inside the marked code entity.
- It is mostly about [already mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214894/is-there-a-resharper-comment-directive-to-disable-code-cleanup-for-a-class), I will show you how to get the same things in last ReSharper builds. All you need is to add "System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute" to "Non-reorderable types" pattern in ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | File Layout.

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:[image]

Step 3: [image]

Step 4:[image]

Step 5:[image]

To make sure your colleagues use the same settings in ReSharper, save this change to the [Solution team shared layer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html#solution-team-shared-layer) (`Save To` at the bottom of the Options dialog). Then if any of your colleagues opens the solution, ReSharper will automatically use the setting from this layer with no additional actions required.

Comment: This is however a workaround to a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-459432), isn't it?